# How to uninstall completely BOOST 1.71

Tags: apt, package-management, libraries, boost

I am trying to remove completely `Boost 1.71`. I need to downgrade to a previous working library as from the version `Boost 1.71` I am receiving `'boost::placeholders' has not been declared` so I want to downgrade to `Boost 1.66`.

After typing on the terminal the `ldconfig` I am left with only one instance:

```
emanuele@emanuele-pc:~$ ldconfig -p | grep libboost
    libboost_thread.so.1.71.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.so.1.71.0
```

I tried to remove it using:

```
sudo rm -f /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_*
sudo rm -rf /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_*
```

But still the `libboost_thread` is there..

So I tried accessing via `sudo synaptic` and tried to remove it from there but received the following `broken package` warning:

[image]

Therefore thinking that there was something broken I did:

```
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
udo apt-get install -f
```

but nothing...the `libboost_thread` is still there.

How do I make sure everything is fully removed?

Comment: How was the software installed originally?

Comment: I don't remember because it was a while ago. It could be that I installed it downloading it from the offical webpage and bootstrapped it

Comment: basically I could have followed [this source](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/bbv2/installation.html). But again I don't remember fully.

Answer (score 1):

## Note about using bad methods

**Execution of commands like**

> ```
> sudo rm -f /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_*
> sudo rm -rf /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_*
> ```

**is absolutely wrong. DO NOT DO THIS!

Such library files are controlled by APT, you should ask APT to remove such files first.**

If you have compiled these libraries manually, then you did it wrong. They should be placed in the `/usr/local/lib` prefix. It is not controlled by APT.

## Note about `'boost::placeholders'`

Really this namespace is used in both Boost [1.67](https://github.com/boostorg/bind/blob/boost-1.67.0/include/boost/bind.hpp#L33) and [1.71](https://github.com/boostorg/bind/blob/boost-1.71.0/include/boost/bind.hpp#L33) which are [shipped](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?arch=amd64&searchon=sourcenames&keywords=boost1) with your Ubuntu 20.04 LTS from official repositories. For successful Boost-based development you then have to install the following development packages:

- For already installed 1.71 -

  ```
  sudo apt-get install libboost1.71-all-dev --reinstall
  ```
- For possible 1.67 alternative -

  ```
  sudo apt-get install libboost1.67-all-dev
  ```

## Further notes

If you are really understand what are you trying to do then read below.

You can use the following one-liner to remove ALL occurrences of Boost 1.71:

```
sudo apt autopurge $(dpkg -l | grep boost | grep 1.71 | awk '{print $2}')
```

To remove only [`libboost_thread.so.1.71.0`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=amd64&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=libboost_thread.so.1.71.0) you have to execute:

```
sudo apt purge libboost-thread1.71.0
```

if the above command fails, then go lower level and execute as fallback

```
sudo dpkg --purge --force-all libboost-thread1.71.0
```

and then run

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```